# Arrays based on nd array condition

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to set a single column in a numpy array to the condition of two other columns, element-wise.  I but can't seem to get it quite right, I have tried `np.where`, `np.which`, and `np.all`.

I know I could do this with a for loop, but speed is important in this task and want to use the built-in array functions.

I would like to set `predicted_probabilities[:,1]` to remain true if it is already true, but also become true if  `predicted_probabilities[:,0]` and `predicted_probabilities[:,2]` are both false

For example:

```
predicted_probabilities = np.asarray([[True, False, False],
                                      [False, True, False],
                                      [False, False, True],
                                      [False, False, False]])
```

I would like my `predicted_probabilities` to ultimately be:

```
[[ True False False]
[False True False]
[False False True]
[False True False]
```

I have tried:

```
predicted_probabilities[:,1] = (predicted_probabilities[:,0] & predicted_probabilities[:,2])
```

I have also tried

```
predicted_probabilities[:,1] = np.where(predicted[:,0]==False & predicted[:,2] == False)
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You need some `()` to give priority to the `==` tests: `(predicted[:,0]==False) & (predicted[:,2] == False)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `np.logical_and` and `np.logical_or` may help.

```py
import numpy as np

predicted = np.asarray([[True, False, False],
                        [False, True, False],
                        [False, False, True],
                        [False, False, False]])

cond = np.logical_and(predicted[:, 0] == False, predicted[:, 2] == False)
predicted[:, 1] = np.logical_or(predicted[:, 1], cond)

print(predicted)
"""
Prints:
[[ True False False]
 [False  True False]
 [False False  True]
 [False  True False]]
"""
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @algotrade Glad it helped! Please accept my answer to mark the issue as closed if that is the case :)